# Using np.savetxt and np.loadtxt with multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, file-io, numpy, multidimensional-array

What is a generalized way of storing a more-than-2 dimensional array (`ndim > 2`) to file and retrieving it in same format (dimension) using `np.savetxt` and `np.loadtxt`?

My concern is if I give any delimiter while storing, do I need to give some treatments while retrieving? Plus dealing with floats and retrieving it in same format is little tricky.

I have seen many simple examples in the docs. I am just curious about whether the simplest storing `np.savetxt(filename, array)` can be retrieved using simply `array = np.loadtxt(filename)` or not.

Comment: do you have to use text files? Because the easiest way is to use `np.save()` or `np.savez()`...

Comment: Well I tried with delimiter ',' . and I can retrieve it as simply loading it using np.loadtxt() into numpy array and reshaping it ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to save multi-dimensional arrays in a text file you can use the `header` parameter to save the original array shape:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random((2, 3, 4, 5))

header = ','.join(map(str, a.shape))
np.savetxt('test.txt', a.reshape(-1, a.shape[-1]), header=header,
           delimiter=',')
```

And to load this array you can do:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    shape = map(int, f.next()[1:].split(','))
    b = np.genfromtxt(f, delimiter=',').reshape(shape)
```

Comment: Is this just for .txt ? Because for .dat i think numpy is having some more capacities to handle preservation of format ..

Comment: @Hima it work with any extension and the format you control using the `fmt` argument of the `np.savetxt()` function...